# How to update infowindow of a marker?

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps, google-maps-markers

[image]

```
 for(i=0; i<locations.length; i++) {
        var position = new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][2], locations[i][3]);
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: position,
            map: map,
        });
        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
            return function() {
                infowindow.setContent(locations[i][1]);
                infowindow.setOptions({maxWidth: 200});
                infowindow.open(map, marker);               
            }
        }) (marker, i));
        Markers[locations[i][4]] = marker;
    }
```

I have map has multiple markers with infowindows my aim is to update marker infowindow but could not manage to find a solution.

Comment: If you have a single marker, is `infoWindow` successfully reachable? In other words: do you update the wrong `infoWindow` or do you have problems updating `infoWindow` in general?

Comment: have problem updating infoWindow after initiated it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are trying to store `i` in closure then you can do it like this: [Demo JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bam7kw3s/20/)

```js
  for (let i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
    let position = new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]);
    let marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: position,
      map: map,
      title: locations[i][0]
    });

    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function (event) {
      let content = `<b>${locations[i][0]} </b><br>
            ${locations[i][3]}<br>
            Position: ${event.latLng.lat()}, ${event.latLng.lng()}`;

      infowindow.setContent(content);
      infowindow.setOptions({ maxWidth: 200 });
      infowindow.open(map, marker);
    });
  }
```

Or you can get position from [event object](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/events?hl=en#EventArguments) `event.latLng.lat()` and get the location using it.

---

Or you can have separate info window [for each marker](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/events?hl=en#EventClosures).

Comment: İs it possible to update marker infowindows out of this listener manually? For instance in a timer?

Comment: If you truly want to make it dynamic then the event object has `event.latLng` position object. From the position you can reverse map the object in `locations` array. You can create the reverse lookup map at the start.

Comment: Thank you very much. Do you have a example for that? I can update locations easly by the way with myMarker.setPosition(position); but can not the infowindow

Comment: I found a way to update info marker with  google.maps.event.trigger(myMarker, 'click'); it triggers like user clicks on marker.